# Getting value from 3 Textviews and converting to int for Countdown Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, textview, countdowntimer

Currently I have three textviews which I am using for the countdown timer in my android app in HH:MM:SS. (hours, minutes and seconds). I am allowing the user to set the textviews to a specific number for the time. I am then trying to get the value from the textviews by converting to int and then using the integer values as the seconds for the countdown timer. But the problem is that there is no values for the ints, and therefore the timer cannot start.

[image]

As the user drags around the scrubber he can change the textview value for hours, minutes, or seconds:

Here is the code for that below in my onCreate method:

```
  @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                                                      boolean fromUser) {

                            int progress_count = 0;

                            for (int i=0;i<24;i=i+1)
                            {

                                if (progress ==120) {
                                    mSeekArcProgress.setText("24");

                                }
                                else if (progress == progress_count)
                                {
                                    mSeekArcProgress.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%02d",i)));
                                }

                                progress_count = progress_count + 5;



                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.minutetext) {
                    //corresponding button logic should below here

                    mSeekArc.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
                        }


                        //This sets the actual string for the minutes
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                                                      boolean fromUser) {
                            int progress_count = 0;

                            for (int i=0;i<120;i++)
                            {

                                 if (progress ==120) {
                                     mSeekArcMinuteProgress.setText("00");

                                 }
                                else if (progress == progress_count)
                                {
                                    mSeekArcMinuteProgress.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%02d",i)));
                                }

                                progress_count = progress_count + 2;


                            }

                        }
                    });
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.secondtext) {
                    //corresponding button logic should below here
                    mSeekArc.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
                        }


                        //This sets the actual string for the seconds
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {



                            // so ur setting it to HALF of what "progress" is = to

                            int progress_count = 0;

                            for (int i=0;i<60;i++)
                            {


                                if (progress ==120) {
                                    mSeekArcSecondProgress.setText("00");

                                }
                                else if (progress == progress_count)
                                {
                                    mSeekArcSecondProgress.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%02d",i)));
                                }

                                progress_count = progress_count + 2;


                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
```

The TextView ID's are referenced in the following code which is in my setActionListener method for the countdown timer:

```
  private void setActionListeners() {

        // IT IS RIGHT BELOW CHECK IT OUT.



        number_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour_progress_number);
        minute_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minute_progress_number);
        second_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second_progress_number);

         hourint = Integer.valueOf(number_text.getText().toString());

         minuteint = Integer.valueOf(minute_text.getText().toString());

         secondint = Integer.valueOf(second_text.getText().toString());




        totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = ((hourint*60*60) +(minuteint*60) + (secondint)) * 1000;      // time count for 3 minutes = 180 seconds
        timeBlinkInMilliseconds = totalTimeCountInMilliseconds/1000;



        start_timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               // textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.normalText);

                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
                    // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500 milliseconds

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                        long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
                        mSeekArc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);





                        if ( leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds ) {
                           // textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.blinkText);
                            // change the style of the textview .. giving a red alert style

                            if ( blink ) {
                                number_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                minute_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                second_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                // if blink is true, textview will be visible
                            } else {
                                number_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                minute_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                second_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            }

                            blink = !blink;         // toggle the value of blink
                        }



                        second_text.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
                        minute_text.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60));
                        number_text.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 3600));                     // format the textview to show the easily readable format
                    }




                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                        //textViewShowTime.setText("Time up!");
                        number_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        minute_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        second_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mSeekArc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }.start();

            }
        });
    }
```

The timer works went I put an explicit integer value for totalTimeCountInMilliseconds; however, when I use hourint, minuteint, and secondint the value is probably zero because the timer doesn't start and that seems like that is the only valid reason.

I am not sure what to do the fix this so I can get integer values and make the timer work.

**EDIT**: Pastebin for full code link:    http://pastebin.com/1wcXHdvX

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Log.i("YourActivity","Seconds: " + secondsint);
```

to check, what are the values you get from textviews.

Dont forget to add imports. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and select the Android Logcat import.

**EDIT1:**

I looked you code and you are calling setActionListeners() in your OnCreateMethod(). That does not make sense! setActionListeners() get the values from the TextViews from the user. But User cant enter values when system initializes the activity. So, call your `setActionListeners()` here:

```
start_timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   setActionListeners();

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      ...
   }
 ...
}
```

And move the start_timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){...})
to onCreateMethod()

Comment: How would I get the proper value?

Comment: Because it is not my intention for it to be zero

Comment: @XiJiaopin Edited my answer. You should look, what Methods actually do and how they work. And also look more in the official documentation of Android API.

Comment: Okay I see. Will do. Also I get an error in setActionListeners saying that it is an invalid method declaration when I move the start_timer.setOnClickListener to onCreate. tryna figure out why